# Find Equation of a Perpendicular Line Going Through a Point

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, parametric

I have the following parametric equation for line g:
$$
x=3t\land y=-7+5t\land z=2+2t
$$
I have to find the equation of a line perpendicular to $g$ and going through point $Q(3,-2,4)$ which lies on $g$.
I know I have to use the dot product but can somebody tell me the whole procedure.

Thank you in advance `:]`

Answer (score 2):

The equation of line can be written as: $$L:\frac{x-0}{3}=\frac{y+7}{5}=\frac{z-2}{2}=t$$ So the leading vector of the line is indeed, $\vec{u}(3,5,2)$. Since you are supposed to find the equation of perpendicular line to $L$ so, you have to find an appropriate vector $\vec{v}(a,b,c)$ such that $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=0$$ You may use some other ways to find such this vector, but I suggest you in this problem to find $a$,$b$ and $c$ but examine some values for them such that: $$3a+5b+2c=0$$ For example, $$a=+1,~b=-1,~c=+1$$ Now write the equation of your line.

Comment: So for example: x=3+1s; y=-2-s; z=4+s ?
Isn't there a countless number of such lines?

Comment: @ДилянТрайков: We have countless number of perpendicular vectors like $v$ instead ,but the constrain "passing through $Q$" exclude many infinite lines.

Comment: Are the lines `x=3+1s; y=-2-s; z=4+s` and `x=3+2s; y=-2-2s; z=4+2s` the same? If not, are they both perpendicular to `g` and passing through `Q`?

Comment: @ДилянТрайков: For checking if the are both perpendicular to $g$, probe if $3(+1)+5(-1)+2(+1)=0$ and $3(+2)+5(-2)+2(+2)=0$? It seems that both are normal to $g$ but which ones are passing through $Q$? If both one is passing through $Q$ so they are the same line. :)

Comment: But how can lines
`x=3+2s y=-2+8s; z=4-23s`
and
`x=3+20s y=-2-2s; z=4-25s`
be the same (for example)?

Comment: @ДилянТрайков: They are not as they're written. The leading associated vectors are different.

Comment: Well, their dot product with (3,5,2) is the same?

Comment: Could you please write the final answer of this task because I'm obviously not getting it :D

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$ I hope you awaken refreshed and joyous!

Comment: @amWhy: I created a new tag as `multiplicative-groups`. I don't know how to edit its wiki and other processes. Can u help me? Thanks

Comment: @mrs Why can you take any of the values a, b and c that suit the equation of the dot product?